# How to execute multiple aggregate in one trip to mongodb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to execute multiple aggregate in one trip to mongodb.
in some case on one collection and in another on multiple collection.
is it possible?
if its possible,how?

excuse me for bad english.

My collection is some thing like this :

```
{
    _id: ....,
    Name: "Name1",
    LastItem: {
        _t: "Type3",
        Count: 5,
        Date: 2017
    },
    Items: [{
        _t: "Type1",
        Count: 1,
        Date: 2016
    },
    {
        _t: "Type2",
        Count: 0,
        Date: 2013
    },
    {
        _t: "Type3",
        Count: 5,
        Date: 2017
    },
    {
        _t: "Type4",
        Count: 2,
        Date: 2010
    },
    ]
}{
    _id: ....,
    Name: "Name2",
    LastItem: {
        _t: "Type1",
        Count: 8,
        Date: 2017
    },
    Items: [{
        _t: "Type1",
        Count: 8,
        Date: 2017
    },
    {
        _t: "Type2",
        Count: 10,
        Date: 2014
    },
    {
        _t: "Type3",
        Count: 50,
        Date: 2015
    },
    {
        _t: "Type4",
        Count: 12,
        Date: 2011
    },
    ]
}{
    _id: ....,
    Name: "Name3",
    LastItem: {
        _t: "Type3",
        Count: 15,
        Date: 2016
    },
    Items: [{
        _t: "Type1",
        Count: 11,
        Date: 2009
    },
    {
        _t: "Type3",
        Count: 15,
        Date: 2016
    },
    ]
}
```

i want to execute 2 below aggregates in one trip to mongodb :

1- `groupBy => Name`
   `where => items containe (Type3)`
   `return => count(Name)`

2- `groupBy => Name`
   `where => LastItem._t = Type3`
   `return => count(Name)`

Comment: You don't. Better to describe what you actually need to do by example data, as there is most certainly a solution to your actual problem, but your question does not actually provide enough information. Present a solvable case and someone will solve it.

Comment: Can you describe better what you means "Multiple Aggregation"?

Comment: Aggregation Framework is able to perform Multiple Aggregation at same time by using $facet; is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Your question can be resolved in a single Group operation like this:

Comment: {$unwind: "$Items"}
   
   ,{
    $group: {
     _id: "$Name",
     Type3_in_Items: {$sum:   {$cond: [{$eq: ["$Items._t", "Type3"]}, 1, 0]   }},
     Type3_Counts_in_Items: {$sum:   {$cond: [{$eq: ["$Items._t", "Type3"]}, "$Items.Count", 0]   }},
     Type3_in_LastItem: {$addToSet:   {$cond: [{$eq: ["$LastItem._t", "Type3"]}, 1, 0]   }}     
     }
   }
  
   ,{$sort: {"_id": 1}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB 3.4 is able to process multiple aggregation framework pipeline at same time by using $facet.

*The $facet stage allows you to create multi-faceted aggregations which characterize data across multiple dimensions, or facets, within a single aggregation stage. Multi-faceted aggregations provide multiple filters and categorizations to guide data browsing and analysis. A common implementation of faceting is how many online retailers provide ways to narrow down search results by applying filters on product price, manufacturer, size, etc.* [LINK](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

This is not something to use "any time you want". In my opinion you should consider to optimise your pipeline instead of create multiple time-consuming pipeline.

Then your problem can also be resolved by combining some condition inside the same $group. This is an example, you can customise it  easily.

```
 {$unwind: "$Items"}

   ,{
    $group: {
     _id: "$Name",
     Type3_in_Items: {$sum:   {$cond: [{$eq: ["$Items._t", "Type3"]}, 1, 0]   }},
     Type3_Counts_in_Items: {$sum:   {$cond: [{$eq: ["$Items._t", "Type3"]}, "$Items.Count", 0]   }},
     Type3_in_LastItem: {$addToSet:   {$cond: [{$eq: ["$LastItem._t", "Type3"]}, 1, 0]   }}     
     }
   }

   ,{$sort: {"_id": 1}}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: will you tell me! why we won't use multiple aggregation instead of single aggregation